# Blank RAM type for Samsung laptop

Tags: windows, laptop, memory, samsung-laptop

I want to find compatible RAMs for my Samsung laptop. I'm trying to see which DDR type my motherboard supports on Windows, but both Task Manager and CPU-Z don't show the DDR type.

Task Manager:

[image: Task Manager]

CPU-Z:

[image: CPU-Z]

Motherboard:

- **Motherboard Manufacturer**: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO. LTD.
- **Motherboard Model**: NP350XBE-KDABR

Is my RAM not a DDR SDRAM?

This is my laptop: https://compare.techtudo.com.br/produto/notebook-samsung-np350xbe-kdabr-celeron-4205u-1-80ghz-4gb-500gb-padrao-intel-hd-graphics-610-windows-10-home-essential-e20-15-6-polegadas-1110814

#### UPDATE

According to @Bib comment, I searched for `np350xbe-kdabr ram upgrade` and I purchased a RAM from Crucial (CT8G4SFRA32A, [this one](https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/memoria-ram-color-verde-8gb-1-crucial-ct8g4sfra32a/p/MLB17451543?pdp_filters=item_id:MLB2188570544)) that is said to be compatible with my laptop model (NP350XBE, compatibility list [here](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/samsung/np350xbe)). However, when I replace the RAM, the laptop doesn't start. When I put back my old RAM, the laptop still works. Will it work if I combine my old RAM with the new RAM from Crucial?

Comment: Is it really too difficult to search on`np350xbe-kdabr ram upgrade`?

Comment: @Bib I searched like you said and got a Crucial RAM for $56. If I replace my laptop's RAM with this Crucial RAM, the laptop doesn't start. If I put back my old RAM, the laptop starts fine. What I didn't still try was combining the two. Would combining them work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My laptop supports DDR4 RAMs, although Windows doesn't show it. My new RAM didn't work because it was installed the wrong way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).